# std::list problem for iPhone development

Tags: iphone, stl

I found some problems for `std::list` when I'm doing some iPhone development under Xcode. Here is the code:

```
///////////// interface //////////////

class CObj
{
public:
    int value;
};

typedef std::list<CObj*> ObjList;

@interface testAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    ObjList     m_objs;
}



//////////// implementation /////////

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{    

    for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++ )
    {
        CObj* obj = new CObj;
        obj->value = i;
        m_objs.push_back(obj);
    }

    NSLog(@"%d objects",m_objs.size() );

    ObjList::iterator it = m_objs.begin();
    while (it != m_objs.end()) 
    {
        CObj* obj = *it;
        if ( obj->value == 3 )
            it = m_objs.erase(it);
        else
            it++;
    }

    NSLog(@"%d objects",m_objs.size() );
}
```

The application simply crashes at m_objs.push_back. But if I change the `std::list` to `std::vector`, everything's fine. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: What's the crash message say? Is there a stack trace?

Comment: As an aside, there's another bug in the code: you aren't deleting the object you're removing from the list. You need a 'delete obj' next to the erase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Objective-C does not call the constructor for c++ types on initialization.

If you set this flag in the build settings "**Call C++ Default Ctors/Dtors in Objective-C**", it will change the default behavior. Be aware that the flag only shows up if you have the target set to Device.